# Which window manager is this and how do you get a terminal with tiny borders?

Tags: linux, window-manager, xterm, rxvt

I came over the below configuration and was wondering which window manager he was using, and how you get an rxvt/xterm terminal to look like that.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

You really could have found this out yourself with only a tiny amount of initiative exercised.  I only had to hit the "Up" hyperlink to the enclosing picture gallery to find that it's Claude Lecommandeur's `ctwm`.  It's right there, named both in the screenshots themselves (in one of which `.twmrc` is being edited with `gvim`) and in the screenshot filenames (`ctwm_knuta_1280x1024`, for example).

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say, could be any number of the minimalist window [managers](http://xwinman.org/others.php)

Answer (score 0):

At first glance, it looks like [Enlightenment](http://www.enlightenment.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like evilwm to me.

Website:

> http://www.6809.org.uk/evilwm/

Screenshot:

[image: screenshot]